# Unset fields as required for a Form

Tags: forms

In my drupal-based project, we make a difference between laptop users and tablet users: Laptop users **can skip some fields when registering**, whereas tablet users have to fill in all of them. The trick is easily done by **hiding or showing those fields from the signup form** with jQuery and Modernizr. And I say trick, because it works, despite some of those hidden fields being marked as `required`, they are still allowed to signup without filling on them.

The problem comes when users forget their password and request a link to create a new one.
When they get to the screen of *"Enter new password and confirm it"*, users who have initially signed up via laptop (i.e., not filling on some of the `required` fields), cannot continue because they get the error **"Fields X and Y cannot be left blank"**, or sth similar.

I want to **disable these 2 fields from being `required` for Drupal** (not from the signup form, where I have already "hidden" them), but I am not sure how to proceed. Where should I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest, you use **hook_form_alter()** and then check for laptop users. If laptop users are on form then make **#required** false for these two fields.

**Example:**

```
$form['title']['#required'] = FALSE;
```

**Note:** FYI Avoid using *unset()* in such type of scenario either set the *#access* property or *#required* property to FALSE. This keeps them in the form build tree, which avoids problems if other modules try to access or alter that information.

Comment: I am afraid I am a bit newbie for your answer... I would need something more like "go to this table in MySQL, search for X in field F and set 'required' to FALSE"... Either in the MySQL or in the Drupal admin panel. But I would definitely disable for all users.

Comment: @Jago first you look into https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7 and keep in mind never change in db directly there are number of options available to deal with such type of options. In your case you create custom module, create hook_form_alter and print the $form array and then do override respective fields as I suggested. You simply make field optional to avoid validation issue. Once you do all this stuff then share your code with us, if problem persists.

Comment: Ok, fair enough. Can you point me to some good example of usage of this? The module is already developed, I just need to locate where and how to use the function. So, can you provide a good example of usage? Thanks

Comment: I am adding to `hook_form_FORM_ID_alter()` the following: `$form['card_holder_name']['#required'] = FALSE;` but it does not seem to work. I always get the message that the field is still required...

Comment: I also tested this code at my end it works for me after clearing cache. I am sure it would also work for you, can you share your complete module code with me. And also confirm you are using correct form field name. If still you find issue with this, then please share your code I would fix this for you.